# how to get above average from Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, querydsl

I have a question about QueryDSL in Elasticsearch.
This is a test query.

```
GET index/_search {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "groupByClass": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "group"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avgGroup": {
                    "avg": {
                        "field": "score"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get values greater than avgGroup such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM index
WHERE score > (SELECT AVG(score) FROM index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch won't do that for you. You need to handle this externally. using a script or in an application.

Document sample:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name":"chemistry",
    "score": 15
}
```

Average query:

```
{ 
    "aggs" : {
        "avg_score" : { "avg" : { "field" : "score" } }
    }
}
```

Then pass avg_score value to second query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "score": {
                "gte": //avg_score //avg_score value set here in your application side
            }
        }
    }
}
```